# IPtables: Forwarding

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-12.04

I have an Ubuntu machine running as a firewall. This machine has our static IP configured on eth1. It is connected to our network via eth0.

I have a new server running Server2012 with IIS installed. It is a sharepoint server. I need the sharepoint server to be accessible to the internet and the local network via a domain name. i.e. "awesomebox.net"

What is the IPTables rule I need to make this happen?

Where I'm at:

I have a rule in the nat table to redirect incoming requests to our sharepoint server. It works OUTSIDE our building. When I try to access it from INSIDE our building, I get the apache server on our local firewall.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.100.XX.XX:80
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.100.XX.XX -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.100.XX.XX:443
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -d 10.100.XX.XX -j ACCEPT
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you really obscure your RFC1918 addresses? That's rather pointless...

Comment: Sorry if it bothers you. I'm just a programmer who has been forced into some server admin stuff. Not sure what the rules are around here so it's better safe than sorry.

Comment: You don't _have_ to obscure anything, as far as we care. In fact, it's almost always better if you don't. Only if you have sensitive information would you need to consider obscuring it, (like the name of your company) but RFC1918 addresses aren't, by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are only applied to packets entering on `eth1` from the Internet, and so won't be applied to packets entering on `eth0` from the LAN. Either add another set of rules specifying `eth0`, or remove that condition from the current rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.100.XX.XX:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.100.XX.XX -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.100.XX.XX:443
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 443 -d 10.100.XX.XX -j ACCEPT
```

If the SharePoint server is connected to `eth0` you're going to run into the [hairpin NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT#NAT-loopback) problem. To address this you need to SNAT the outgoing packets if the source is the LAN subnet:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.100.XX.XX -s 10.100.XX.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -d 10.100.XX.XX -s 10.100.XX.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Thanks.

Wouldn't the first set of commands redirect all traffic bound for Port 80 to my internal server? i.e. if a user is trying to reach Google he's going to wind up talking to my internal server.

Just making sure, I already "broke the internet" once today, I'm trying not to do it twice. :)

Comment: @JasonMaggard Ah yes, you're correct. You should match the target IP specifically (edited).